# How to replace a fragment dynamically in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

In the following example, I only want to create a simple `main.html` layout, and `home.html`, `about.html`.

The subpages should only contain their own content body, not header or footer inclusions.

This is what I have so far, but how could I now dynamically replace the `container` content with the page that was clicked?

```
<html>
  <body>
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home">Home</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="container">
       <p>This should always get replaced when a link is clicked</p>
       <!--<div th:replace="fragments/pagename :: pagename">-->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I'd only had one page, I could replace the content with `<div th:replace="fragments/about :: about">`, but how could I do this dynamically?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking... have you checked out thymeleaf layout dialect?  Thymeleaf is a server side language, so you can't replace thymeleaf fragments without a full refresh of the page.

Comment: A full refresh would be ok. My main concern is that I don't know how I could just create one single main.html layout, and then dynamically replace the `container` fragment above when clicking a link in the navbar. So if "Home" is clicked, the home.html content should get injected at the position of the container fragment.

Comment: Did you check out layout dialect? https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect -- I think it makes more sense for this kind of thing than thymeleaf replaces.

Comment: Ok that works, but if I use eg `<section layout:fragment="content">` Thymeleaf logs that the support for this expression will be dropped in future releases. So I'd be looking more into a native thymeleaf approach. But if I got your right, thymeleaf natively lacks this feature? I could hardly believe that, because most webpages nowadays would use a common layout, and just looking to replace the content pane as part of the webpage. How do others solve that? Just copy the header, navbar and footer fragment over into every single content page? That would contradict any DRY programmers principle...

Comment: Correct, thymeleaf out of the box does not support the kind of inversion you want (which is specifically what layout-dialect is for).  I personally use it in all my thymeleaf projects (it's even mentioned on the [thymeleaf website](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html#thymeleaf-layout-dialect)) as the built in replace/insert is just not good enough.  As for the message you are receiving about it being deprecated... I'm not sure (I can't see it in my projects).   Are you sure it's not talking about using fragment expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deprecation message came from `<html layout:decorate="layout">`. Rewriting it to `<html layout:decorate="~{layout}">` fixed the message.

Anyways, `thymeleaf` seem to lack this important feature, thus using the `thymeleaf-layout-dialect` layout dialect is the only way to go.